# Growth rate of number of divisors of Highly Composite Numbers

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, divisibility

Let $H(k)$ be the $k^{th}$ highly composite number (HCN).

1. What is an asymptotic estimate for the size of $H(k)$ in terms of $k.$
2. What is an asymptotic estimate for the size of $d(H(k))$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Even though there are a lot of related questions and answers on Math Stackexchange, I haven't been able to find clear answers to these questions. Also, can one answer these questions for Superior HCNs?

**Edit:** A page at Bielefeld university [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.html) has numerical evidence suggesting
$$
\ln H(k) \sim \ln 2 (\ln k)^{4/5}.
$$
Has such a result been proved?

Comment: I cannot answer 1, but presumably the answer to 2 is certainly not going to be more than what corresponds to the bound $$\lim \sup \log d(n) = 2 \frac{\log n}{\log \log n}.$$ Anyone care to comment?